# MySQL monthly diffs

Tags: mysql

i spent lot of time to search a solution to my problem. i think i'm near the solution but my final request doesn't work...

first of all, i have a table that represent water index based on 10 minutes sampling.

```
----------------------------------
| DateTime            |  Counter |
----------------------------------
| 2020-05-13 15:00:03 | 38450    |
| 2020-05-13 15:10:03 | 38454    |
| 2020-05-15 15:00:03 | 38500    |
| 2020-06-02 12:10:03 | 38510    |
| 2020-06-15 12:10:03 | 38600    |
----------------------------------
```

Some samples could be not present in the table
so i would like to extract a table to see my consumptions by days, week, month, year

i have found many examples, but none works as i expect...
for the example table above, i expect to get:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| fromDateTime        | toDateTime          | fromCounter | toCounter | diff |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2020-05-13 15:00:03 | 2020-06-02 12:10:03 | 38450       | 38510     | 60   |
| 2020-06-02 12:10:03 | 2020-06-15 12:10:03 | 38510       | 38600     | 90   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i have writen a query

```
select mt1.DateTime as fromDateTime, 
       mt2.DateTime as toDateTime,
       mt1.Counter as fromCounter, 
       mt2.Counter as toCounter,
       (mt2.Counter - mt1.Counter) as diff
from WaterTest as mt1
    left join WaterTest as mt2
    on mt2.DateTime=(
        select max(dd.datetime) as DateTime from (SELECT MIN(DateTime) as DateTime
            FROM WaterTest as mt3
            WHERE month(mt3.DateTime) = month(mt1.DateTime + INTERVAL 1 month)
        union ALL
        select max(DateTime) as DateTime
            from WaterTest as mt4
            where month(mt4.DateTime) = month(mt1.DateTime)
        ) as dd
    )
```

But MySql results with an error saying "Field 'mt1.DateTime' unknown in where clause"
is someone can help to find where i'm wrong ?
Am I on the good way to achieve this ?
(and for sure, if there is a more powerfull request.... :) )

Comment: What are the actual timeframes over which you want to aggregate?

Comment: Can you explain how 2020-05-13 15:00:03 | 2020-06-02 12:10:03 represents a days consumption? Or if not a day what is it?